Is the last of "happy" a distinct phoneme?
As I've read the y in happy is pronunced /i/, but is it a distinct phoneme? My guess is that it could be regarded as a allophone of /iː/ or /ɪ/. I've read that it's pronunced the same as either of these in some dialects.
Or put in another way is there a minimal pair between /i/ and /iː/, or /i/ and /ɪ/?

@StuartF Not really, the question is if there's a minimal pair between the "happy" /i/ and the other i-sounds.

The last vowel of HAPPY has no stress. The FLEECE and KIT phonemes have stress (not always primary stress, but stress all the same). How could there possibly be a minimal pair between a stressless vowel and a stressed one? The two words would have different stress patterns, thus inviting the reply that they are not a minimal pair.

@RosieF Certainly stress affects things like length, tenseness, and the offglides of non-phonemic phonetic diphthongization, but it's a widespread misleading myth that things like stress matter about the vowel, like people saying that schwa is only ever in unstressed syllables. Throw out the distressingly confusing length markers and you won't be so confused by all this. Our outdated "standardized" notations are locked into nonsense from a century ago that no longer apply today and therefore quite understandably confuse the heck out of just about everybody.

@RosieF You're conflating word stress and sentence stress. Syllables that are stressed within words when said on their own may not be stressed in connected speech. The "happy vowel" is either a KIT or a FLEECE in SSBE, depending on the speaker and for some speakers you might see free variation. This variation only happens in unstressed open syllables. However both KIT and FLEECE occur in both stressed and unstressed positions. For example the KIT vowel that occurs in  the -ING suffix is not stressed, and neither is the one that occurs in the plural -es nominal suffix either.

@RosieF To see what I mean about stress in connected speech, you could try the following (if you're one of those who has a FLEECE for their HAPPY vowel): "Blue tea or admiralty" and "Blue tea or admiral tea" the last vowel of the first would be transcribed as /ti/ but the last of the second would be /ti:/. However, I doubt you can find a listener who can hear the difference - because there ain't any!

@Araucaria-Him I've come across that in a pun: "Why do Marxists drink herbal tea? Because property is theft." The linguistic issue is: is the pun exact? I'd say "no" because the stress patterns are slightly different. Likewise, "incite" and "insight" aren't homophones. (That latter word pair was cited by Rhymoid from Wikipedia.) I know a word might be stressed in some contexts and not in others, but I wasn't talking about that.

@RosieF Yes, incite and insight have lexical stress on different syllables and thus are not homophones. However [ edit ] the second "tea" is not stressed in "Blue tea or admiral tea", because the "tea" is old information (it's repeated) and therefore becomes destressed, thereby leading to the homophone. There would be no homophone if it was "hot chocolate or admiral tea/admiralty"!
